# Hosting Python Script with I/O in <div> on website

Tags: python, html, terminal

My goal is fairly simple, I have written a python 3 script that runs on an ubuntu server at my workplace. Currently I (and other users) have to SSH into this ubuntu box anytime we want to run the script, which with a growing number of users is getting messy - from a convenience and security standpoint. So my boss would like me to create a nice webpage-based GUI to access this script and some other similar scripts I have written.

This seems like a straight forward thing, but the difficulty is in the details - the script is used for viewing and editing records so it has a lot of back-and-forth communication with the user (using `input()`) as well as screen clears and code like the following:

```
sys.stdout.write("\033[F") #back to previous line
sys.stdout.write("\033[K") #clear line
```

...to keep things clean and within one terminal.

If absolutely needed of course I could modify the script to accept inputs in a different format and output in a more html-friendly method without line and screen clears, but this would be rather tedious to redo for the whole script. SO - my question is what would be the best way to achieve what I'm after with minimal modifications to my written code? Ideally the webpage would just have a  container holding a terminal-like graphic that handles all the input and output of the selected script as if it was running through a full fat terminal.

Things I've already looked into include basic python web frameworks such as CGI or mod_wsgi, or a python package like flask, but - correct me if I'm wrong - it seems there isn't a nice way to handle constant inputs within scripts with these let alone the terminal-oriented clearing I do for clearing lines and screens.

I also looked into ways to just host a full terminal on the webpage, and security concerns aside, this seems like the closest solution - using something like ajaxterm (which seems rather outdated now?) or wetty. My main concern with this is it isn't any easier than just using SSH at that point. Unless I could modify the terminal to auto-login and start a specific script automagically with the push of a button on the webpage, this would just be a glorified web-rendition of putty.

Any suggestions on how you would achieve this?

Comment: you could do something like this in flask or django, but it's going to involve some changes to your code, not sure you're going to get around that. You could package your script into an executable and distribute that way i guess.

Comment: It actually used to be an executable, then we consolidated for updating purposes. Any thoughts on flask vs django for this task?

Comment: I haven't used flask really, so I can't give a good comparison, but django worked pretty well for me. You'll need to do enough html and JS to give it a usable UI, but plugging your script into the back end should be relatively easy.